# Kiyotaki-Moore v.s. Bernanke-Gertler-Gilchrist - what's the difference?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-economics, new-keynesian-economics, business-cycles

What are the key differences between (i) a model which features a "Kiyotaki-Moore collateral constraint"; and (ii) a model which incorporates a "financial accelerator" (a la Bernanke-Gertler-Gilchrist)?

Both have impulse responses which fluctuate due to borrowing being tied to the net worth (or collateral) of borrowers.

So would there be any difference between their modelling outcomes?